# How can I speed-up a matrix rotation by 90 degrees clockwise?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix, rotation

Rotate a square matrix by 90 degree with O(1) extra space. I have used Python to solve it. I wanted to know if I can improve my code further.

```
def rotate_by_90(m):
  # unpacking arguments with zip(*) in reverse with [ : :-1]
  tuples = zip(*m[::-1])
  # flattening tuples to list with [list(i)]
  return [list(i) for i in tuples]

def makeMatrix(array, size):
  # validating size of matrix for given array
  if (size**2!=len(array)):
    return -1
  # make sub array of length size using array slicing  
  else:
    matrix = [array[i:i+size] for i in range(0, len(array), size)]
    return rotate_by_90(matrix)

arr = [1,2,3,4]
dimension = 2
result = makeMatrix(arr, dimension)
# Original Matrix: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
# Result: [[3, 1], [4, 2]]
```

Comment: Can you define `improve` in the context of your question? Faster? What's wrong with it right now that requires improvement?

Comment: Yes, is it possible to make it anymore faster? For example if the dimension is  increased to 10000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No external libraries or zip needed. Use this for interviews:

1. Flip it by the x axis.
2. Swap the coordinates diagonally

`def rotate_by_90(m):
    a.reverse()
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(i): 
            a[i][j], a[j][i] = a[j][i], a[i][j]
    return a`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for speed you are using the wrong type of array. You need to switch to numpy arrays instead of lists. And in Numpy there is of course a function for operations like this: [rot90](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. will try that.